# How to immobilize widget layout when keyboard is open?

Tags: ios, android-layout, keyboard, flutter-layout, flutter-cupertino

I am developing a Flutter App. In a specific screen, I have a Cupertino style text field. (The whole app is Cupertino, I have four TabBars below the screen). Whenever I click on the textfield, the virtual keyboard opens and all the widgets squeeze between the textfield and the keyboard (with yellow-black bands of course).

The widgets are Expandable rows and columns (Flexible also has the same result).

resizeToAvoidBottomPadding is disabled.
resizeToAvoidBottomInset does not have any functionality.
SingleChildScrollView does not work.
ListView is meaningless, since my widgets are stateless and static.

What I need is to have keyboard open on top of the current widgets, instead of moving them. This problem exists both in iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple of weeks, I finally reached the solution. Despite indicating 'resizeToAvoidBottomInset' as not working above, I was using that in one of the folders of tabs. However this should be added where you build the tabs.